# Pass very large variable from Java app to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

What is the quickest way to export a very large string (several megabytes) from a Java app to on-page javascript? At the moment it's taking so long the browser grinds to a halt.

Here is the code I'm using to modify the DOM:

```
window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
document = (JSObject) window.getMember("document");
for (int i = 0; i < encHexFileUploadStr.length(); i++){
    char c = encHexFileUploadStr.charAt(i); 
    document.eval("document.getElementById('encOutgoingData').value += '"+c+"';");
    if (i % 100 == 0) document.eval("console.log("+i+");");
}
```

Before this I tried to just assign the encHexFileUploadStr variable directly in one go, that was no better.

Is there any good way to do this that isn't so slow?

Thanks!

Comment: Converted to comment: This looks horrific
`document.eval("document.getElementById('encOutgoingData').value += '"+c+"';");` how about not using eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not attempted to transfer the amount of data you are mentioning from a Java application to a webpage, however, if you are using document.eval the performance problem you are having is most likely due to the processing required on an eval statement.  An alternative approach is to directly invoke a JavaScript method which performs the actual data update work.  Here is an example of how you would go about using this approach:

**Java**

```
JSObject jso = JSObject.getWindow(this);
// invoke JavaScript method updateData with parameter encHexFileUploadStr
jso.call("updateData", new String[] { encHexFileUploadStr });
```

**JavaScript**

```
function updateData(s) {
    document.getElementById('encOutgoingData').value = s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine Kris' suggestion with breaking the string in chunks of 1024 bytes or such and append to a string in JavaScript and at the end copy, in JavaScript, the string to the field

[How do I optimize this method for breaking a string in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891969/how-do-i-optimize-this-method-for-breaking-a-string-in-chunks)

Also in the loop, make it a habit to do

```
for (int i = 0, n=something.length();i<n; i++){
```

rather than

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.length(); i++){
```